# Find files with regex and their respective directory

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I'm working on the 'C:\Documents' directory.

It has many subdirectories and I need to find all the files that their filename starts with 'A0' prefix and ends with '.xls' extension. For example, 'A0SSS.xls' or 'A0ASDF.xls'

Is it possible to fetch all those files and get their directory?

For instace, if the file 'A0SSS.xls' is located on 'C:\Documents\Folder1', I need to know the file name (A0SSS.xls) along with their respective directory (C:\Documents\Folder1).

Answer (score 2):

To find the path of the matching files, you  run a recursive search with a filter. I recommend for you to use pathlib, so you can easily get the parent folder for each of them. The list of parent folders can be redundant, if you have got multiple matching files in the same folder. There are many ways to make a list unique in python. One of them is to convert the list to set, which must be unique by definition, and convert it back to list.

```
from pathlib import Path

search_path = Path("C:\Documents")
results = list(search_path.rglob("A0*.xlsx"))
string_results = [str(matching_path) for matching_path in results]
containing_folders = [r.parent for r in results]
unique_folders = list(set(containing_folders))

print("matching files:")
for r in string_results:
    print(r)
print()
print("containing folders:")
for f in unique_folders:
    print(f)
```